# How rank candidate based on multiple data points in Ms excel sheet using formula

Tags: excel, ranking

I have 10 candidate having achievement data points on 4 parameters. Please help me out to rank them based their achievements on excel formula.

[image: EXCEL TABLE WITH DATA POINTS AS PARAMETER 1, PARAMETER 2...]

I'm learning excel with using various formulas. Please help me out, as I have to rank my candidates based on 4-6 parameters.

Comment: You should give some more information, it seems that you want the community to do your job. We can help you, if you provide some more information or maybe an screenshot of what you currently have, and what would you like to get.

Comment: Please explain in words what the logic is to arrive at the final rank and also post what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just a "final rank" column alone, it sounds like you want to sum up the ranks from the initial 4 parameters, then rank the final. If that is the case, you could first add a Final Score column, in which you would have a formula like this:

```
=SUM(D2,F2,H2,J2)
```

Then, rank that Final Score column in the next column using something like this:

```
=RANK.AVG(K2,K$2:K$11)
```

These formulas assume that your "SR NO." is in column A and that there are no skipped columns. So, "VALUE RANK", "PAR 2 RANK", "PAR 3 RANK", and "PAR 4 RANK" are in columns D, F, H, and J. Column K would be the Final Score column and J would contain the final rank.